# select best parameters for regression model using Gridsearch

Tags: python, machine-learning, linear-regression, grid-search, lasso-regression

I'm doing linearregression modeling and i used gridsearch for select best parameters. below python steps i followed for this work but i got error (ValueError: Invalid parameter alpha for estimator LinearRegression(copy_X=True, fit_intercept=True, n_jobs=None, normalize=False). Check the list of available parameters with `estimator.get_params().keys()`.) please help for me to select best parameters for my model..

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
reg = LinearRegression()
parameters = {"alpha": [1, 10, 100, 290, 500],
              "fit_intercept": [True, False],
              "solver": ['svd', 'cholesky', 'lsqr', 'sparse_cg', 'sag', 'saga'], 
             }
grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=reg, param_grid = parameters, cv = 2, n_jobs=-1)
grid.fit(x_train, y_train)
reg.score(x_test,y_test)
```

Comment: There is no `alpha` parameter in sklearn's `LinearRegression()`

Comment: thanks for your help..i'm beginner for machine learning. i'll correct that mistake.

Comment: @CeliusStingher Then how to tune best hyper param in case of  LinearRegression?

Comment: Just answered the question @AmitModi :)

Answer (score 2):

This is because there is no `alpha` parameter to be adjusted in `sklearn.LinearRegression()` therefore you are passing an invalid argument to a function, generating the `ValueError` you get.

You should look into this [functions documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html) to understand it better:

> sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression(*, fit_intercept=True, normalize=False, copy_X=True, n_jobs=None)

From here, we can see that hyperparameters we can adjust are `fit_intercept`, `normalize`, and `n_jobs`. Each function has its own parameters that can be tuned. Take for instance [ExtraTreeRegressor](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.ExtraTreesRegressor.html) (from extremely randomized tree regression model) also from sklearn:

> sklearn.ensemble.ExtraTreesRegressor(n_estimators=100, *, criterion='mse', max_depth=None, min_samples_split=2, min_samples_leaf=1, min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0, max_features='auto', max_leaf_nodes=None, min_impurity_decrease=0.0, min_impurity_split=None, bootstrap=False, oob_score=False, n_jobs=None, random_state=None, verbose=0, warm_start=False, ccp_alpha=0.0, max_samples=None)

As you can see the parameters that can be fine-tuned are a lot more, perhaps allowing for more flexibility in the model. Make sure you correctly understand each model and its tune-able parameters before applying `GridSearchCV` randomly.